# ListView does not update despite binding to DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, ado.net

As usual, i did a little research, but couldn't quite find the answer on the site or elsewhere. if you can pointy me to an existing question I'd be appreciative. Otherwise, here is the question:

I have a `ListView` object binds to a `DataTable` object. See definitions below:

```
<ListView Name="MyList">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="Column1Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Column1}" />
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="Column2Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Column2}" />
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="Column3Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Column3}" />
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="Column4Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Column4}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The binding code is as follows:

```
DataTable items = new DataTable();
items = DatabaseService.GetMyItems(20, true, items);
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = items.DefaultView;
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
MyList.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

The actual code that performs the query is as follows :

```
/** Parameters: commandText = <sql>, table = items */    
using (DbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Project.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = commandText;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                using (DbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
                    dataAdapter.Fill(table);
                }
            }
        }
```

This code works the first time but when I call the `GetMyItems` method again after the data has changed, the data does not refresh.

***What am I doing wrong?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's working first time is working from the constructor, once loaded your view then you need to [notify that your property change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx).

Within your GetMyItems method use:

```
OnPropertyChanged("items");
```

And then declare the method:

```
  // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
  {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
  }
```

It's usual if you are not using a prebuilt MVVM Framework to inherit from a NotifyPropertyChanged object in order to get the OnPropertyChanged method in your ViewModels.

It doesn't matter that you had an observable property within the DataTable, the problem is the change notification. You need an **ObservableCollection**. You can convert DataTable (DataSet is constructed by one or more DataTables) into ObservableCollection and then [bind ObservableCollection to UI element](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/94238dc4-00c4-4af4-afb9-195f89ece621/).

Comment: DataTable is already in .Net Framework APIs (using 4.0) -`System.Data.DataTable`. The observable list property is `Datatable.DefaultView` has an event called `ListChanged`([link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.100).aspx)).